# Backbone.js and global instances

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, design-patterns

we're pretty new to backbone and building a new app with it.. we're using the standard namespacing ie:

```
(function($) {
   window.Lara = {
     Models: {},
      Collections: {},
     Views: {},
     Events: {},
     Templates: {}
   };
   var vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
}(jQuery));
```

We need to keep state of certain views so that they're accessible across the different models and views, my question is where should instances be held of all the models and views etc... I'm finding it hard to keep things within scope between all the events and different views so I could just put all the needed global instances somewhere within the App namespace... is this the right approach?

I feel like the defined Lara.Models, Lara.Views etc should be kept clean and as a template for instances... should I just create an Lara.Instances and dump them all in there?

Any suggestions would be great here!

Comment: checkout this article on Backbone extensions, I think Marrionette might be interesting to you: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/make-backbone-better-with-extensions/

some other people have gone through this and come up with their own answers.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure about your questions, you need refs to your existing views/models?

I would keep an reference for important models like UserSession in the Application scope, for your case, it would be something like

```
Lara.currentUser = new Lara.Models.UserSession() # Set it when user logs in
```

Is this something you are looking for? Leve me the comment